# C# System.ArgumentException: "Empty path name is not legal."

Tags: c#, path, argumentexception, c#-ziparchive

I'm messing about with winforms and zip programs. Now, the first hiccup I had was that it didn't force any extension when I tried to save it, so if I typed in a name it just saved it as a file. I fixed this with: (although, if I typed in name.rar it worked fine, but we want the .rar part to be automatic, of course)

```
saveFileDialog1.Title = "Izberi kam naj se datoteke kompresirajo";
saveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "rar";
saveFileDialog1.Filter = "RAR Files (*.rar)|*.rar";
saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
```

Now it forces .rar as an extension, although, it's in the "Save as type" drop-down, not in the name itself.

When I try to save it with just a name; it throws the "empty path name is not legal" error, it does the same thing if I input .rar at the end.

Here's the rest of the code of the button; the others work fine. It happens at the `ZipArchive zip = ZipFile.Open` line.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    saveFileDialog1.Title = "Izberi kam naj se datoteke kompresirajo";
    saveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "rar";
    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "RAR Files (*.rar)|*.rar";
    saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;


    DialogResult result = saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        if (isFolder)
        {
            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(textBox1.Text, saveFileDialog1.FileName);
        }
        else
        {
            string[] files = textBox1.Text.Split(',');
            ZipArchive zip = ZipFile.Open(saveFileDialog1.FileName, ZipArchiveMode.Create);
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                zip.CreateEntryFromFile(file, Path.GetFileName(file), CompressionLevel.Optimal);
            }
            zip.Dispose();
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Uspešno!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Debug and check value of `saveFileDialog1.FileName` and `file` in `foreach (string file in files)`. It should not be empty string.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I understand. I'm very new to all of this.

Comment: Learn how to debug your code in Visual Studio. Add break points at places where ever you use `saveFileDialog1.FileName` and `file`. Whenever the break point is hit, check the value, if it is empty or not? If its empty? what the cause?

Comment: files is   {string[1]} string[] ; but saveFileDialog1.FileName is " ", so does that mean that I have to input a file name? For example *.rar? Because whenever I try to continue to anything over ZipArchive zip it stops everything and throws the error again.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your findings in the debug.

If FileName is blank, you will get this error. You need to input a filename.

You can add extra check:

```
if (result == DialogResult.OK && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(saveFileDialog1.FileName))
```

Comment: Okay, now it doesn't throw that error out anymore, but what happens is;

When I first start to debug the program and choose a file to compress, it goes through (it doesn't save, and there's no message box, the folder window just closes, but if I try to compress it again (still running the program) it will say inside of the window to save; "File *.rar does not exist. Verify that the correct file name was given."

And it doesn't matter if I input the extension on my own or not.

So basically, I need to add a FileName?